# Dot product with rotations

Tags: geometry

suppose $x$ and $y$ are two vectors such that the usual dot product $x\cdot y>0$. Lets now replace $x$ by $\gamma x$, i.e. if $i$-th entry of vector $x$ is $x_{i}$, then the new entry is $\gamma_{i}x_{i}$, where $\gamma_{i}>0$ for all $i$.
How do I show that $(\gamma x).(\gamma y)>0$?

Comment: I don't see a rotation - the $\gamma x$ is some other kind of linear transformation.

Comment: You cannot show it as the statement is not true. Example: $x = [3\,\, -2]$, $y = [1\,\, 1]$, $\gamma = [1\,\, 100]$.

Comment: By the way, for the future, you may want to write $\gamma \circ x$ instead of $\gamma x$ and call the former the Hadamard product of $\gamma$ and $x$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)

Comment: Note that if $\gamma$ was an actual rotation, this theorem would be true. But as you've defined it $\gamma x$ is not a rotation, and it is easy to come up with a counterexample to this rule. Given that your title says "rotation," perhaps you have the definition of $\gamma x$ wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This is only true if the $\gamma_i$ are equal. Intuitively, $x\cdot y>0$ means that the angle between the vectors is acute, and your $\gamma \circ x$ can be any element in the same quadrant(*) as $x$. So we can pick $y=(-1,1)$, $x=(1,2)$ and $\gamma=(4,1)$ to gives us a counter-example.

If $\gamma \circ x$ is not in the same direction with $x$, we can always find a vector $y$ which is at an acute angle to $x$ but not relative to $\gamma\circ x$.

(*) What is the terminology equivalent to quadrant in dimensions higher than $2$? Not sure.

With the altered question, it still doesn't work. Let $x=(1,2)$ and $y=(-1,2)$.  Let $\gamma = (4,1)$.

Comment: In three dimensions, it is called an "octant." Number $16$ in Latin in apparently "sedecim," so I conjecture that in $4$ dimensions it is called a "sedecimant."

Comment: the question was wrong, both the vectors are multiplied by $\gamma$...its edited now

Answer (score 0):

Take $$x = (2,-1) $$ $$ y = (1,1)$$ $$ \gamma = (1,10)$$

than $$ \gamma \circ x \cdot \gamma \circ y = 1\cdot 2 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 - 10 \cdot 1 \cdot 10 \cdot 1 = 2-100 = -98$$